# Flutter JSON response value null handling

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, rest

I have a list of contacts which I'm displaying in `Future Builder` `ListView` from API response, I have a total of 23 contacts in the server but I want to leave out all the contacts whose `firstname` and `lastname` is `NULL`.

**Before handling of NULL Exception:** [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rzAc.png)

**Code:**

```
                      Container(
                          height: 50,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              contact.fields.all.firstname == null
                                  ? Container()
                                  : Text(
                                      contact.fields.all.firstname +
                                          " " +
                                          contact.fields.all.lastname,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

**After handling of NULL Exception:** [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXWwK.png)

**As you can see from the code and image added, to handle the exception I simply returned an empty `Container` for all contacts with `firstname` having null value but now I want to change that. Instead of returning a empty Container how can I make those contacts with both `firstname` and `lastname` as `null` not show up on the screen at all?**

Answer (score 0):

you can remove elements with null from the list before returning the result

```
// contacts = jsonDecode(someApiCall());
   contacts.removeWhere((contact) => contact.fields.all.firstname == null && field.lastname == null);

return contacts;
```

if your data is a map you can use something like

```
myMap.removeWhere((key, value) => myMap[key] == null);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering but my JSON is not in a List format, it is a Map. Any other way I could do this?